# AWS EC2 issue slow instance VolumeQueueLength

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-scraping, server

I am experiencing an issue with my EC2 instance. I am scraping different websites using R programming and it works fine but after some hours, my EC2 instance is freezing.

After raising a ticket to AWS support, they noticed that this was caused by the rise of the "VolumeQueueLength" which then was decreasing the BurstBalance credits from 100 to 0.

See below when I tried around June 19th:

[image]

Would you know what is causing this VolumeQueueLength to go up?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: If your EBS burst balance is falling to 0 you are using more IOPS than the volume can handle. You need to either increase the size of the volume, switch to provisioned IOPS, use instance storage, or change your app to not be so disk intensive.

Answer (score 1):

From [I/O Characteristics and Monitoring - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-io-characteristics.html):

> If your I/O latency is higher than you require, check VolumeQueueLength to make sure your application is not trying to drive more IOPS than you have provisioned. If your application requires a greater number of IOPS than your volume can provide, you should consider using a larger gp2 volume with a higher base performance level or an io1 volume with more provisioned IOPS to achieve faster latencies.
>
> For more information about Amazon EBS I/O characteristics, see the [Amazon EBS: Designing for Performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wKgha8CZ_w) re:Invent presentation on this topic.

This is basically saying that the IO allocated to an Amazon EBS 'General Purpose' volume is proportional to its size, so a larger volume might solve your IO problems. Alternatively, you could consider moving to a *Provisioned IOPS* volume (which is faster, but more expensive).

Your application seems to be using more IO than has been allocated for the volume.